# Constructing exponential function using a table of outputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been given the exponential function $g(x)=ar^{x}$. I have also been given the table $(x=4,g(x)=\frac{256}{3})$, and $(x=5,g(x)=\frac{1024}{9})$.... Now as far as I understand you can take $\frac{1024}{9}$ and divide it by $\frac{256}{3}$... This should give you the $r$ value.. I'm trying to wrap my head around why that works?

Comment: $g(x+1)/g(x)=$?

Comment: Did you notice that $256=2^8$, $1024=10^{10}$, $9=3^2$ ? this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In an exponential, adding unit to the function multiplies it by the value of $r$.
$$a\cdot 2^x = [a\cdot 2^1=a\cdot 2,a\cdot 2^2=a\cdot 2\cdot 2^1=a\cdot 4,a\cdot 2^3=a\cdot 2\cdot 2^2=a \cdot 8...]$$
The value of $a$ becomes irrelevant since they are expressed in both $g(4)$ and $g(5)$